# How to alter TabBar tab background color in custom TabNavigator component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml

I'm creating a custom `TabNavigator` component to be used in other applications.  Right now though, the background of the tabs will not change (although other style changes do apply).

in my `CustomTabNavigator` class, I have this override:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList (w:Number, h:Number):void {
    super.updateDisplaylist(w,h);

    tabBar.styleName="CustomTabBarStyle";
}
```

And here is the css in the `<style>` declaration:

```
.CustomTabBarStyle {
    tabHeight:100;
    tabWidth:100;
    tabStyleName: "CustomTab";
    backgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
}

.CustomTab {
    backgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
    color: haloBlue;
}
```

The haloBlue color of the text is applied, as well as the tabHeight and tabWidth.  The background color isn't changed though.  I've been through about 5 tutorials trying different things, to no avail... is there a way to do this within a custom component?  All I'm trying to do is get rid of the gradient background in place of a flat white background.

Comment: Try to use .CustomTab {
    chromeColor: #FFFFFF;
    color: haloBlue;
}

Comment: @IlyaZ, that made the background of the selected tab pure white, so progress :) Do you know the reason why it won't apply to the other tabs?

Comment: Which flex version you use? Try use chromeColor in .CustomTabBarStyle class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by extending the TabBar and ButtonBarButton classes.  I then made a separate skin for the custom ButtonBarButton that used a custom background color pulled from a new field in the custom class (e.g. `hostComponent.tabBackgroundColor`).

If someone has a better solution using the CSS method, I'd be happy to accept that instead (as that was what I was originally asking for).